# Full Calendar Event timings are appearing as allDay even though the time is saved in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I am trying to have the events display on the right spot based on their time slots selected. So once the event is created, it does get saved in the database with the right time slot but when it comes to displaying them, they all show up in the top as all day events and not as a regular event with their timings in the database.

Here is the var_dump from the events.php

```
  [{"id":"1","title":"Umar","start":"2016-03-15 00:00:00","end":"2016-03-18 00:00:00","url":"www.ua.com","allDay":"false"},{"id":"2","title":"Abdullah","start":"2016-04-04 00:00:00","end":"2016-04-04 00:00:00","url":"www.abdullah.com","allDay":"false"},{"id":"7","title":"Abou AbdurRahman","start":"2016-05-09 00:00:00","end":"2016-05-13 00:00:00","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"12","title":"Abdullah","start":"2016-05-17 03:00:00","end":"2016-05-17 11:30:00","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"13","title":"Ahmad","start":"2016-05-18 01:00:00","end":"2016-05-18 06:00:00","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"14","title":"Abdullah Break","start":"2016-05-19 10:00:00","end":"2016-05-19 16:00:00","url":null,"allDay":"false"},{"id":"15","title":"asd","start":"2016-05-20 07:00:00","end":"2016-05-20 12:30:00","url":null,"allDay":"false"}]
```

And here is the event render for the calendar :

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
     defaultView:'agendaWeek',
     events: "events.php",
     timeFormat: 'h:mm',
     displayEventEnd :true,


    // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
     eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

        event.allDay = false;

     },
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     select: function(start, end, allDay) {
           var title = prompt('Event Title:');


      if (title) {
          var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss a');
          var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss a');
         console.log("Event Triggered");
         $.ajax({
                 url: "add_events.php",
         data: 'title='+ encodeURIComponent(title)+
            '&start='+encodeURIComponent(start)+
            '&end='+encodeURIComponent(end),
      //    +  '&url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
                 type: 'POST',
         dataType:'text',
                success: function(json) {
                                         alert('Added Successfully');
                 },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                         alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
         });
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
             title: title,
             start: start,
             end: end,
        //   url:url,
             allDay: allDay
        },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
 }
```

Any help to get to the bottom of this issue would be appreciated.

Regards,
Umar

Comment: Please define 'right spot'. It is not clear what you are trying to do. You could provide example input with detailed description of expected output. Also, are you getting specific errors, or do you have missing functionality which you just don't know how to implement?

Comment: @HenryTK
As you can see in var dump that there are events with time slots. So they do not appear in the right time slot, they appear in allDay slot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtStartDate').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                yearRange: "-3:+1",

                onClose: function () {
                    var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $('#hdnStartMonth').val(parseInt(iMonth) + 1);
                    $('#hdnStartYear').val(iYear);
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));

                    if (parseInt($('#hdnEndYear').val()) < parseInt($('#hdnStartYear').val())) {
                        $('#txtStartDate').val('');
                    } else if (parseInt($('#hdnEndYear').val()) == parseInt($('#hdnStartYear').val())) {
                        if (parseInt($('#hdnEndMonth').val()) < parseInt($('#hdnStartMonth').val())) {
                            $('#txtStartDate').val('');
                        }
                    }
                },

                beforeShow: function () {
                    if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                        iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                        iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
                        $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                        $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#txtEndDate').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                yearRange: "-3:+1",

                onClose: function () {
                    var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $('#hdnEndMonth').val(parseInt(iMonth) + 1);
                    $('#hdnEndYear').val(iYear);
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                    if (parseInt($('#hdnEndYear').val()) < parseInt($('#hdnStartYear').val())) {
                        $('#txtEndDate').val('');
                    } else if (parseInt($('#hdnEndYear').val()) == parseInt($('#hdnStartYear').val())) {
                        if (parseInt($('#hdnEndMonth').val()) < parseInt($('#hdnStartMonth').val())) {
                            $('#txtEndDate').val('');
                        }
                    }
                },

                beforeShow: function () {
                    if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                        iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
                        iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
                                 $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                        $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what is going on in here so that I understand what to do.

Comment: here is all calendar option. you can perform operation when before calendar  show and alse can perform when calendar is close...